# Convex Hull not outputting expected number of features

Tags: qgis, features, polygon-creation, convex-hull, biology

I have a .csv file with observations of various species and I want a polygon to illustrate the area where those species occur. I ran the Convex Hull, grouped by the species' names field, which returned a feature for each species, as expected.

The problem is that there were some species that weren't expected to return an error because they don't have enough geometries to form a polygon, but **the number of errors was higher than the number of species with 1 or 2 observations.**

What causes the Convex Hull in QGIS 3.14 to return an error?

Comment: Reproducible example?

Comment: Some suggestions: a) many observations at a single point b) three or more observations on a straight line.

Comment: I uploaded two tables i used that have given this error in We Transfer. Link next: https://we.tl/t-0WLxW9SVDP

Comment: I checked the database manually and along with the cases you mentioned, I also noticed that Convex Hull won't create a feature if there are points with identical coordinates. I suggest including it on your final answer